# Unpacking a list in print for Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, printing

I'm having problem with understanding why unpacking does not work with list and print statement in Python 2.7:

```
>>> l=['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> print (*l, sep='')
```

Python 3.x works fine and prints:

```
abc
```

Python 2.7, however, raises an error:

```
 print (*l, sep='')
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I make it work for Python 2.7?

I know I can alternatively code it using join with: `''.join(l)`

Comment: There is no `*` operator in Python 2.

Comment: @EliSadoff: sure there is. It's the [multiplication operator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) (in both 2 and 3). `*` in calls or function definitions is not an operator, however, but does exist in Python 2.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Let me correct myself, there is no unary `*` operator in python 2.

Comment: @EliSadoff: nor is there one in Python 3. It is **not an operator**. It is part of a larger syntax construct. Like a [call](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls) or a [function definition](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions). In Python 3, [expression lists](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists) now support such syntax where in Python 2 they didn't.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because `print` isn't a function in Python 2; unpacking a list and providing it as positional args *isn't possible if it isn't a function*.

You'll need to import the `print_function` from `__future__` in order to support this:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
```

Now unpacking is possible:

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> print(*l, sep='')
abc
```

Answer (score 5):

You have two options:

- Convert to strings and join with spaces manually:

  ```
  print ''.join(map(str, l))
  ```
- Use the [`print()` *function*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print), by using the `from __future__` import that disables the `print` *statement*:

  ```
  from __future__ import print_function

  print(*l, sep='')
  ```

  or directly call the function by accessing it via the [`__builtin__` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html):

  ```
  import __builtin__
  print_function = getattr(__builtin__, 'print')

  print_function(*l, sep='')
  ```

  The same function is available in both Python 2 and 3, but in Python 2 you can't use it directly without first disabling keyword.