# dictionary in a list comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I trying to compress the below code as much as possible and as pythonic as possible, appreciate suggestion.

```
#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
import yaml

FILE='t'

with open(FILE, 'r') as F:
    doc = yaml.load(F)

compr = [x for x in doc]

for x in doc:
    for k,v in x.items():
        print "\n"
        print k
        for k2,v2 in v.items():
            print k2,
            for b in v2:
                print b,
```

the output of doc looks like this:

```
[{'UK': {'City': [1, 2, 3]}}, {'France': {'City': [1, 2]}}, {'US': {'City': [1, 2, 3]}}]
```

My expected output is below:

```
UK
City 1 2 3
France
City 1 2
US
City 1 2 3
```

Comment: What are you asking? This code is Pythonic. Putting it in a list-comprehension would make it *not pythonic*, unless you aren't trying to create a list, but AFAIKT you are just trying to print stuff (which you shouldn't do in a list comprehension, because list comprehensions are for creating lists, not for side-effects). Speaking of unecessary list comprehensions, `compr = [x for x in doc]` -> `compr = list(doc)`

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try unpacking values in `print` but you may need to import `print_function` for python2 as described in other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41047137/5916727):

```
from __future__ import print_function
doc = [{'UK': {'City': [1, 2, 3]}}, {'France': {'City': [1, 2]}}, {'US': {'City': [1, 2, 3]}}]

for element in doc:
    for k1, v1 in element.items():
        print(k1)
        print(*v1, ' '.join(map(str,*v1.values())), sep=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
doc = [{'UK': {'City': [1, 2, 3]}}, {'France': {'City': [1, 2]}}, {'US': {'City': [1, 2, 3]}}]

for dic in doc:
    for country, data in dic.items():
        print(country)
        for city, numbers in data.items():
            print(' '.join([city] + list(map(str, numbers))))
```

Which gives:

```
UK
City 1 2 3
France
City 1 2
US
City 1 2 3
```